# Restore VM from Google cloud snapshots

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a baseline full snapshot (25GB) and the other 6 subsequent snapshots with about 1GB - 3GB in size within a month, now I want to create a new VM instance with the latest snapshot, it only let me pick one snapshot file when create the new instance, how can I apply all the latest subsequent snapshots into the new VM as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

All snapshots but the first are incrementals snapshot. If you select a snapshot to restore, google will automatically consolidate it with the datas from the previous snapshot allowing you to have a complete image.

To get more informations, have a look a this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/restore-and-delete-snapshots